# Dictionary of dictionaries, how to get value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, idictionary

I have something like this:

```
private IDictionary<A, IDictionary<B, C>> data;
```

and I want to do something like:

```
IDictionary<B, C> values = new Dictionary<B, C>();
values = Data.Values;
```

like would I do in java, but this isn't working. I can't figure it out. Thanks for help

error:

Cannot implicitly convert type ICollection> to IDictionary

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: Try this
values = Data[A]; should work

Comment: I'm surprised this had three downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure what will come out, try to use type-inference

```
var coll = data.Values;
```

Then try to acces the `Collection` using a `foreach`-loop to access individual dictionaries.

```
foreach(var dic in coll){
//work on Dictionary
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.values.aspx) for a reference.

Comment: ah I get it now.. by Values I will get collection of dictionaries, not only one dictionary.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would still call `.Values`, but it returns a ValueCollection, not a list.  To get just the values, and not a list of Key/Value pairs, use a Select:

```
List<C> values = data.Values.Select(x => x.value);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx

Comment: yes, and how I can cast ICollection to IDictionary? there is ToDictionary method, but I really dont know how to use it

Comment: You want to go in the *other* direction?  You'll need a way to construct keys for each of the items in your `ICollection` to put into the dictionary.

Comment: data.Values is generic, this can't be used

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an `ICollection` of your `IDictionary<B, C>` which will not work since there any many Dictionaries in the Collection.

If you wish to map all the Dictionaries down then you can use a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx):

```
IDictionary<A, IDictionary<B, C>> data;
var values = data.ToLookup(d => d.Value.SelectMany(d => d.Key), d => d.Value.SelectMany(d => d.Value));
```

Which will give you multiple keys to multiple values.